# How to choose required cluster after k-means clustering in python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means, image-segmentation

i'm doing k-mean clustering on an image (fruit tree image) with k=4 clusters. when i display 4 clusters seperately, fruits goes to cluster1, stem goes to cluster 2, leaves goes to clster3 and background goes to cluster4. i'm further interested in fruit clutser only. the probelm is when i change image to another fruit tree image, fruit cluster goes to cluster2 or sometimes to clsuter3 or 4. my wish is to not change the cluster for fruit, means if fruit is in cluster1 it should be in cluster1 in all images of fruit tree. how can i do that? 2ndly if its not possible i want to select that cluster automatically which contains fruit. how can i do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: K-means only identifies clusters of data in your image, it won’t be able to identify the clustered object itself. If you want to identify fruits, you should consider classifiers.

Comment: If you combine two images, will fruit of both images go into the same cluster? If yes, you could use a primitive nearest neighbor classifier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

K-means clustering is unsupervised, meaning the algorithm does not know any labels. That is why the clusters are assigned at random to the targets. You can use a heuristic evaluation of the fruit cluster to determine which one it is. For example, based on data about the pixels (color, location, etc), and then assign it a label by hand. In any case, this step will require human intervention of some sort.